# Tikz shape library not working on input files

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

Somehow, I can use the `shapes` tikzlibrary only on the current file, with it not working on files loaded via `\input`. Essentially, if I write a file with:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{terminal/.style={shape=rounded rectangle,minimum width=2cm,draw}}
```

And then load it into the main file with:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\input{"inputfilepath"}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) at (0,0) [terminal]{Início};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It gives an error, saying that it doesn't recognize the shape `rounded rectangle`, drawing the node as a regular rectangle instead. But if you remove `\tikzset{terminal...` from the input file and put it in the main file, it suddenly works. What gives?

Comment: Please give the full code of both files.

Comment: @AndréC that is the full code, the only thing that's different is the file path, but the file itself is still loaded, so the problem is almost definitely not there.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with an up-to-date TeXLive installation.